# Have link click trigger unique toggle button?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using AngularJS and just CSS/HTML to create this webpage. I have a list of book links that I loop through and create a new 'card' (just creating a div) for each link. As part of this loop, I am also creating a toggle so that each card has a toggle switch next to it. I want the toggle to be switched on/true when the book link is clicked but right now it only seems to work for the first link as I want. If I click any other link in the list, the toggle doesn't seem to be working.

I essentially have it set up so that when the link is clicked, it triggers toggleSwitch() function which goes and toggles the button. I think the problem is that the way I have my angular written is so that it looks for the first link every time, but I'm not sure how to loop through the list. (I am new to web development so forgive me if this seems dumb)

```html
 <span *ngIf="selectedTitles">
                <div *ngFor="let audibleTitle of selectedTitles" class="justify-content-center">
                    <a  class="bookLink" href="link to a book"  (click)="toggleSwitch()" target="_blank">
                        <div class="audible-title card-body">
                            <strong>title name</strong> <br>
                            title author  <strong> | </strong>
                            <!--<span *ngFor="let genre of audibleTitle.genre"> {{genre}} > </span>-->
                                <span>title genre</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input #link type="checkbox" id="sliderButton" >
                        <span class="slider round" ></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </span>
```

```css
export class ContentRecommendationComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('link') testLink;

  @Input() prometheusResponse: PrometheusResponse;

  selectedTitles: AudibleTitle[] = [];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  toggleSwitch(){
    this.testLink.nativeElement.checked = true;
    console.log('this is showing');
  }

}
```

I want every toggle to be associated to it's correct link. I guess my question is how do I link through every link in angular?

Comment: What is `testLink` in your `toggleSwitch()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I want every toggle to be associated to it's correct link. I guess my question is how do I link through every link in angular?

You need to pass the iterator index of the loop to the toggle function. *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" then pass i to toggleswitch(i).

Answer (score 0):

I don't advise accessing the HTML nativeElement for something like this. You already have an underlying data structure, so you can add a `checked` property to this instead. You are having problems with only being able to check the first link because you are not telling your toggleSwitch() method which `audibleTitle` you want to check or uncheck. Think about the underlying data model, not the HTML itself.

I also question your use of a `(click)` action on a link which also has a `href`. If the link is clicked twice (thereby opening a second window), you will unset its `checked` property. Just food for thought.

**In your TypeScript:**

```
export interface AudibleTitle {
    checked: boolean;
    link: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    audibleTitles: Array<AudibleTitle> = [
        {
            checked: false,
            link: `https://example.com`
        },
        {
            checked: false,
            link: `https://google.com`
        },
    ];


    toggleSwitch(audibleTitle: AudibleTitle) {
        audibleTitle.checked = !audibleTitle.checked;
        console.log('this is showing');
    }
}

    audibleTitles: Array<AudibleTitle> = [
        {
            checked: false,
            link: `https://example.com`
        },
        {
            checked: false,
            link: `https://google.com`
        },
    ];


    toggleSwitch(audibleTitle: AudibleTitle) {
        audibleTitle.checked = !audibleTitle.checked;
        console.log('this is showing');
    }
}
```

**In your HTML:**

```
<span *ngIf="selectedTitles">
    <div *ngFor="let audibleTitle of selectedTitles" class="justify-content-center">
        <a class="bookLink" href="https://example.com/{{audibleTitle.link}}" (click)="toggleSwitch(audibleTitle)" target="_blank">
            <div class="audible-title card-body">
                <strong>title name</strong> <br>
                title author <strong> | </strong>
                <!--<span *ngFor="let genre of audibleTitle.genre"> {{genre}} > </span>-->
                <span>title genre</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <label class="switch">
            <input #link type="checkbox" id="sliderButton">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me because audibleTitle isn't actually the whole link. It just generates the end of a string and so href in this case looks more like 'href="https://website{{audibleTitle.link}}'

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean here. From your code, it looks like your `ngFor` iterates over an array of objects, because I can see you referencing `audibleTitle.link`. My answer is pretty versatile- it doesn't matter whether your `audibleTitle.link` is referencing part of a URL or the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to send the `link` template variable through your `toggleSwitch` method like this:

```
<span *ngIf="selectedTitles">
  <div *ngFor="let audibleTitle of selectedTitles" class="justify-content-center">
    <a  class="bookLink" href="link to a book"  (click)="toggleSwitch(link)" target="_blank">
      <div class="audible-title card-body">
        <strong>title name</strong> <br> title author  <strong> | </strong>
        <!--<span *ngFor="let genre of audibleTitle.genre"> {{genre}} </span>-->
        <span>title genre</span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <label class="switch">
      <input #link type="checkbox" id="sliderButton" >
         <span class="slider round" ></span>
    </label>
  </div>
        </span>
```

Now your `toggleSwitch` would be like this:

```
toggleSwitch(link){
    link.nativeElement.checked = true;
    console.log('this is showing');
  }
```

In this way, in each iteration, `toggleSwitch` will receive the actual link in that iteration, and only that specific switch will be toggled

Comment: I can't pass the link itself right now because I have it so that the ngFor is just returning the tail end of the link rather than the whole thing. So my html looks like this ```html div *ngFor="let audibleTitle of selectedTitles" class="justify-content-center">
    <a  class="bookLink" href="http:awebsite{{audibeTitle.link}}"  (click)="toggleSwitch(link)" target="_blank">

Comment: Then change `selectedTitles` so that it returns the data that you need?